# how to disable print function in python

Tags: java, python-3.x, shell, printing, jar

I have a python code that launches jar file

```
subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'jarfile.jar']
```

The jar file prints some errors to the console.
I can't modify jar file.
How can I block those warnings?
Still, I want my python output to be printed in console. Just those jar warnings.

Answer (score 0):

This could be seen as more of a shell question.
You could throw the output into `/dev/null`

```
java -jar jarfile.jar > /dev/null
```

Comment: Not sure where java is writing its error messages to, but shouldn't there reasonably by also a `2>&1` in your code?